# Finding size of incoming file

Tags: c#, file, sockets

In my server program I am supposed to take a file from client but this can be any size so, how can I figure out its size so I can set buffer size for it. I tried this code but at the end I just get 1kb folder which is not working anymore.

```
             private void checkRequest()
        { // Checks if request is a download or upload request and calls function that fits.
...
...
...
            else if (Request.Contains("Upload")) //If request is upload (Client wants to upload)
        {
            info = Request;
            nickName = Request.Substring(0, Request.IndexOf("Upload")); //Takes nickname
            info = info.Replace(nickName, ""); //Takes nickName of the client and deletes
            info = info.Replace("Upload", ""); //Deletes request.

            if (!sList.Contains(nickName)) //If nick name is unique
            {
                info = info.Substring(0, info.IndexOf("end"));

                sList.Add(nickName); //Adds nick name into a list.
                Receive(info); 
            }
        }
        else
        {
            serverSocket.Close(); // If any problem occurs server becomes offline.
        }
    }
    private void Receive(string receivedFileName)
    {
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024]; //This is the part I can't fit anything.
        activity.AppendText("File downloading to " + fileDir + " destination");
        while (tempSocket.Receive(buffer) != 0)
        {
            File.WriteAllBytes(fileDir + "//" + fileName, buffer); //Creates a new file or overwrites it.

        }
        activity.AppendText("File downloaded..."); // Updates activity log(text box.)

    }
```

Comment: `tempSocket.Receive(buffer)` is not garunteed to always read `buffer.Length` bytes in, you need to check the result from `Receive` and only use that many bytes in `buffer`. Also from the MSDN on [WriteAllBytes](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.file.writeallbytes%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) "*Creates a new file, writes the specified byte array to the file, and then closes the file. **If the target file already exists, it is overwritten**.*", you need to use something that appends instead of overwrites.

Answer (score 1):

Before you do the `File.WriteAllBytes()` function call, write a `Int64` out to the socket with the file length.

Then have your client look for that length first, and set the buffer appropriately.

**Remark**

If you want the TCP Stream to only contain data from the file, you could have a protocol that included multiple sockets:

- Control Socket - This socket waits for connections to tell it that a file needs to be uploaded.  Once a client connects, the client will pass it information, such as `file size`.  The server will then respond with a port for a new socket. (**Data Socket**)
- Data Socket - When the client connects to this socket, it will immediately send the entire file.  Once the server receives the agreed upon number of bytes, it will close the socket.

Comment: It's bad practice to send the size before the data, because it breaks the stream design. A stream doesn't know when it will end until it ends...

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit if you don't you have no way of telling when the file is done transferring unless the other end closes the stream at the end or you check for a special pattern that represents a end of stream (but then you must make sure the file does not contain that pattern before you send it). If you are leaving the stream open it is the only way you can send a arbitrarily sized file. As you said the stream doesn't know when it ends till it ends, so you have to add metadata to tell the receiver how much to expect.

Comment: Oh missed the fact that the stream stays open.

Comment: @WouterHuysentruit I added a remark for a simple protocol that would fit your desires better...

Answer (score 0):

Since you leave the socket open, you'll indeed have to send the size of the file first as Andrew suggested.

But even then, don't read everything into an array in memory, but consider using a [`FileStream`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.filestream%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) and write the data directly to disk in smaller chunks.

Something like:

```
private void Receive(string receivedFileName)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
    // receive file size
    if (tempSocket.Receive(buffer, sizeof(ulong), SocketFlags.None) != sizeof(ulong))
    {
        // failed to receive the size
        return;
    }
    ulong fileSize = BitConverter.ToUInt64(buffer, 0);
    // receive file data
    activity.AppendText("File downloading to " + fileDir + " destination");
    using (FileStream stream = new FileStream(fileDir + "//" + fileName, FileMode.Create, FileAccess.Write)
    {
        ulong totalBytesReceived = 0;
        while (totalBytesReceived < fileSize)
        {
            int bytesReceived = tempSocket.Receive(buffer);
            if (bytesReceived > 0)
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, bytesReceived);
                totalBytesReceived += (ulong)bytesReceived;
            }
            else
            {
                Thread.Sleep(1);
            }
        }
    }
    activity.AppendText("File downloaded..."); // Updates activity log(text box.)
}
```